# script package command line output is small in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I installed the `script` package in Atom to run python scripts. The output is a lot smaller than the editor text, and also I cannot resize the console height. It always takes up the minimum height required, so it changes based on output length which is annoying...

[image]

This does not match the "video" on the `script` home page: https://atom.io/packages/script. How do I get the font size to match the editor font size, and also set a fixed height for the console output?

Atom: 1.27.2 x64,
Script 3.18.1,
Windows: 7 x64 DPI 120%

Answer (score 1):

With regard to small font size, I found a solution here:
https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/1191

That is to locate the script package `script.less` file and add a `font-size` property to it under `.script-view .line`

```
.script-view {
  .panel-body pre {
    background: @tool-panel-background-color;
    color: @text-color;
  }

  .output {
  }

  .stderr {
    color: @text-color-error;
  }

  .line {
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    **font-size: 14px;**
  }
}
```

With regard to not being able to resize the output pane, this issue is also reported here:
https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/1125 and
https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/1637.

It sounds like it may relate to Atom itself and not the script package.